# WebAPI accepts different value for integer

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, data-conversion

I have developed WebAPI which accepts class and with post method type. I am facing really weird scenario here.

I am posting below as json.

```
{
 "MessageID":"fec41da8-655c-4532-af7d-554e1505a663",
 "Number":0009,
}
```

In method, I am receiving Number as 0 - but if I pass 0001 to 0008 - it works fine and I am receiving others as 8. Only for 0009 it converts to 0 for other values it removes other 0s.

```
0002 receives as 2
0009 receives as 0
```

Any idea?

Comment: AFAIK, a number starting with zeroes isn't a valid JSON numeric value. I would try to fix these values rather than working out ASP.NET Web API to accept them.

Comment: If everything up to **7** worked then it's because interpretation as an octal number for 0008/0009 will fail as they are not a valid octal numbers (Lead zeros are the octal signifier in JS).  That is not a valid value for json, can't you simply not submit values with leading zeros or treat them as strings?

Comment: Yes, I can but I am just wondering about it how it works so I can change a way and solve. In my request - response receives with 0 only so how can I change leading 0s?

Comment: @AlexK. It seems like the spec doesn't cover octal numbers while parsers may be able to handle them...

Comment: If its not mentioned then I would say its not supported, `var i = 0100` is `64` in js so there is ambiguity, JSON.parse for example will fail on leading zeros in a number.

Comment: You should focus on fixing your invalid JSON, rather than trying to get Web API to accept it.

Comment: @Amy my api is third party and used by people, I have object which accepts parameter - I cannot control on it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason what I figur out here is your `JSON` is *not a valid* `JSON`

```
{
    "MessageID":"fec41da8-655c-4532-af7d-554e1505a663",
    "Number":0009,
}
```

The valid JSON will be

```
{
  "MessageID": "fec41da8-655c-4532-af7d-554e1505a663",
  "Number": "0009"
}
```

If you will use a the valid `JSON` what I shown here then you can easily serialized it to object of class

```
public class Test
{
    public Guid MessageId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

I have tested it against `WEB API 2.0` and it is working fine.

> In method, I am receiving Number as 0 - but if I pass 0001 to 0008 - it works fine and I am receiving others as 8. Only for 0009 it converts to 0 for other values it removes other 0s.

I didn't find the the above line correct because If I use your `JSON` I am getting 0 in every case even if it number between *`0001 to 0008 or 0009`*.

Answer (score -1):

We can override json format convert function to handle such values.

```
long value2 = text2.StartsWith("0x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? 
              Convert.ToInt64(text2, 16) : 
              Convert.ToInt64(text2, 8); // Here OCTAL!!!
```

Comment: It's sent as a number, not as a string, and it certainly doesn't start with `0x`